# How to use the data stored in a rails serialized field

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the User.guided field set to serialized in my user.rb file:

```
serialize :guided
```

In the DB the values are being stored like so:

```
--- "{\"step1\"=>\"true\", \"step2\"=>\"false\"}"
```

So on my rails view I output the values to JS as so:

```
<script>
var guided = <%= current_user.guided.to_json.html_safe %>;
</script>
```

Then in the js console, guided outputs:

```
"{"step1"=>"true", "step2"=>"false"}"
```

Problem is I can't access the individual values? How do you do that?

As `guided.step1` errors with `undefined`

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`to_json` returns a JSON string. You should parse that string on the client to get the actual object.

For example:

```
var guided = JSON.parse(<%= current_user.guided.to_json.html_safe %>);
```

Also, your code doesn't return actual JSON string, but rather string with ruby hash syntax. There's probably more going on there than you show us. This code works:

```
obj = {"step1"=>"true", "step2"=>"false"}
obj # => {"step1"=>"true", "step2"=>"false"}
obj.to_json # => "{\"step1\":\"true\",\"step2\":\"false\"}"
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that with: jQuery.parseJSON(guided) but that errors with: SyntaxError: Unexpected token =

Comment: Thanks but that also gives the error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token ="

Comment: Ah, I see. It returns a string in ruby hash syntax. That's strange. You should debug that.